# Recording time of post and result

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm posting and receiving a response with cURL. Is there anyway that I can record the time it was sent to the time I received the response? This is who my post and response code looks.

```
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataBeingPassed);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_getinfo ( resource $ch [, int $opt = 0 ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php Please check this out

Comment: Connect Time is what ur Looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the time before the request and compare it to the time after the request -

```
$start_ts = time();

// code that takes some time goes here

echo "This code took" . (time() - $start_ts) .' seconds to execute";
```

With this method, you'll only be able to measure the durration in seconds. The `time()` function returns an [epoch timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch) (Seconds since 01/01/1970).

For some more accurate measurements, you might want to take a look at PHP's [`microtime()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-getinfo.php) a try.

```
CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME - Total transaction time in seconds for last transfer
CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME - Time in seconds until name resolving was complete
CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME - Time in seconds it took to establish the connection
CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds from start until just before file transfer begins
CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME - Time in seconds until the first byte is about to be transferred
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl_getinfo() for this.
Refer to this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php